# How to make timer with timeout

Tags: .net, timer, c#-2.0

I have a slow method, while executing it on timer (System.Timers.Timer). It sometimes gets longer to execute than the timer's timeout, which causes the timer to wait. I want while I set the timer for 30ms for example, after 30ms, to reset the method, not wait. What kind of timer should I use?

EDIT:

```
void OnTimerElapsed() {
      SomeMethod(args1);
      SomeMethod(args2);
      SomeMethod(args3);
}
```

SomeMethod is located in another assembly. It's a sync method which requests data from another application. I don't know why it sometimes hangs. That causes the timer to pause until SomeMethod() continues.

Comment: What is "reset the method" supposed to mean?  Surely you're not talking about Thread.Abort?

Comment: yes, I want to abort the operation after the timer's timeout.

Comment: FWIW it's considered very bad practice to abort threads, as you don't know how to recover from a possible bad state, dispose resources, etc.

Comment: Nobody is going to recommend you abort the method.  You'll have to tell a *lot* more about the method to help us help you find a way to stop it nicely.  A code snippet that shows an outline what it is doing and why it is taking so long is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `System.Timers.Timer` and set the its `AutoReset` to false, and only start it when the previous elapsed finished or at your custom condition. Here is the pattern that I use:

```
private System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
private volatile bool _requestStop = false;

private void InitializeTimer()
{
    _timer.Interval = 100;
    _timer.Elapced += OnTimerElapced;
    _timer.AutoReset = false;
    _timer.Start();
}

private void OnTimerElapced(object sender, System.Timers.TimerEventArgs e)
{
    //_timer.Stop();//if AutoReset was not false

    //do work....

    if (!_requestStop)
    {
        _timer.Start();//restart the timer
    }
}

private void Stop()
{
    _requestStop = true;
    _timer.Stop();
}

private void Start()
{
    _requestStop = false;
    _timer.Start();
}
```

**Edit:** If you like to *watch* the timer and if the operation takes longer time then you should not use timer in the first place, instead use wrap your operation in a new thread and use `MaunalResetEvent`, use its `WaitOne` method to specify the timeout, if the timeout occurs then stop or about the operation.

Comment: Using a System.Timers.Timer makes the OP's problem significantly worse, he'll have multiple threads executing OnTimerElapsed.  Very, very bad.

Comment: ok, but if "do work" takes a long time to finish, it will also hang until it checks for requestStop

Comment: @blez I edited the answer to specify an alternative solution.

Comment: @Hans: I didn't understand from the question that he wants to Abort the thread, I edited the answer when I saw his comment to you that he wanted to Abort the operation..